# Passing data from value in javascript to Controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have some problem with passing data from JavaScript to controller.

Scenario: User click save button, the sub_total that already count in js saved into database. I'm getting problem with passing data sub total into controller and saved into database.

Here is my js.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $radios = $(':radio[name^="que_mcr_"]').change(function () {

            var totalPrice = $radios.filter(function () {
                return this.checked && this.value === '1'
            }).length;

            var percentage = totalPrice / 4;
            var total = percentage * 30;

            $('#sub_total_mcr').val(total + " %");
        });
        $radios.first().change()
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = Input::all();
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'eva_pro_acp_id' => 'required|unique:eva_pro_acp_mcrs|max:255',
                'que_mcr_1' => 'required|max:255',
                'not_mcr_1' => 'required|max:255',
                'que_mcr_2' => 'required|max:255',
                'not_mcr_2' => 'required|max:255',
                'que_mcr_3' => 'required|max:255',
                'not_mcr_3' => 'required|max:255',
                'que_mcr_4' => 'required|max:255',
                'not_mcr_4' => 'required|max:255',
                'sub_tot_mcr' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(url("eva_pro_acp_mcr/create"))
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
    }

    $modelEvaProAcpMcr = new EvaProAcpMcr();
    $modelEvaProAcpMcr->fill($data);
    $modelEvaProAcpMcr->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
    $modelEvaProAcpMcr->save();
    \App\Classes\AuditTrailHelper::logAuditCreate("eva_pro_acp_mcrs", $modelEvaProAcpMcr->id, $data);
    return $this->showRecordSaved($request);
}
```

And this is my route.

```
    <?php
Route::get("eva_pro_acp_mcr/export/{type?}", "EvaProAcpMcrController@index");
Route::resource('eva_pro_acp_mcr','EvaProAcpMcrController');
```

How can i create the js and controller to passing the data.

Comment: what is the problem now ?

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. PHP/Laravel runs on the server. I think what you want is a Form submitted to Laravel controller, but the data is modified with Javascript before submitting.

Comment: Do you have a form which submits the data? An Ajax function? @Jacob Goh probably has the right suspicion.